# Favorite tags are not highlighting Firefox 8

Tags: bug, status-norepro, firefox, tag-watching

I am using Firefox 8 on my home PC, and Chrome on my Laptop. On my laptop's chrome, the favorite and ignored tags work right. They blur my ignored tags, and highlight my favorite tags. My laptop also has Firefox 3.6 That works fine as well.

I did search the meta site for "Firefox favorites", this question was not mentioned.

If this has been reported, by all means close it if it is a duplicate.

**EDIT**

Here are some screen shots of SO under different browsers.

1. Firefox 8. This is what I use. All add-ons disabled since the upgrade from 3.6

   [image: Firefox 8]
2. IE 9. I have never used this browser on this machine.

   [image: IE 9]
3. Chrome. I installed this yesterday.

   [image]

My home PC is a Intel i-3, 4 GB RAM, NVIDIA GEForce 9500 card, and AOC monitor. It does not have any additional software apart from Windows and VLC player and the Skyrim game. I am not behind a proxy, since I do not require that information entered anywhere on my system to access the Internet.

Also this is not a show stopper for me. Just thought I should let you know, if it is a bug or something.

Comment: No repro here with FF8.

Comment: What URL were you visiting when experiencing this?

Comment: @NickCraver I visit these two URLs the most.
http://stackoverflow.com/
http://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @desaivv - Working fine here in Firefox 8, look at your console, it's likely another addon/extension/user script throwing an error.

Comment: On my home PC I get the same results under IE 9. Now this is troubling. I have Win 7 32 bit. Intel i3 processor with 4 GB RAM, User memory set to 3 GB for gaming. I think it might be my home PC, not the site. Do not know what could be the problem.

Comment: @NickCraver I have no addons on this PC under Firefox. Same with IE. IE safe mode also does not highlight the favorites. I am pretty sure it is this PC. Just do not know what is causing it under two different browsers. Sorry about the inconvenience. It is not a site bug, atleast I do not think.

Comment: I did a fresh install of Google Chrome on the home PC. Same problem.

Comment: @desaivv, can you upload screenshots somewhere and link to them from your question? This way, we will know if it's a software problem on your end or if something's wrong with your video hardware, your monitor, or your eyes.

Comment: Other jab in the dark: favorite/ignored tag styling is entirely performed client-side. Did you perchance disable scripting in all your browsers, or would some proxy upstream strip some of the scripts from the HTTP responses?

Comment: It would not let me insert 3 links. So the Chrome link has spaces in them. Sorry about the cheating.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with those screenshots - the questions with your favouite tags are been as usual

Comment: @desaivv - I also don't see anything wrong with the screenshots, your favorite tags appear highlighted...what's the issue?

Comment: Ah I see this image on my laptop and the highlighting is there on the image. My home PC, the image also is not highlighted. So sorry to waste your time. I think it is my monitor or my graphic card on my home PC.

Comment: Welcome to the "I fell for my monitor suddenly changing contrast" party...happened to me some days ago. ^^

Comment: @Bobby it really was the contrast. Thanks a lot.